# Triggering Gmail's Report Phishing Feature

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail

Is there a way to trigger Gmail's "Report Phishing" option from a Gmail Add-on?

Our Add-on allows users to report the message internally to our own IT staff, and we would like to report to Google at the same time rather than asking users to report it twice.

I cannot find any documentation that suggests it is possible but figured it wouldn't hurt to ask.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Would reading the contents of the mail and extracting the URI's out of it in order to send it via the Phishing Protection API count as a solution?
[Quickstart for the submission API](https://cloud.google.com/phishing-protection/docs/quickstart-submission-api)

Comment: No, as it does not notify the administrator.